# Poor canvas animation performance with a lot of lines

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm building a chart using canvas.
This chart has lot of lines (up to 300) and each line has a lot of strokes (200 each, more or less).

I'm facing some performance issues. Simply the `lineTo` function is consuming a "lot" of processing time, making the zoom and panning kinda laggy.

I have developed a simple [Code Pen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqwoxP). It's not my real chart but it reproduces the problem: when zooming and panning you can feel the animation is lagging.

I'm feeling I'm doing something wrong here (like clearing and redrawing everything everytime) but I really don't know what it is or how should I proceed if not redrawing everything.

Can someone help me improve this performance?

Thanks!

Comment: how about somethings like http://www.chartjs.org ? I am not familiar with this though

Comment: Unfortunelly it doesnt provide the interactivity that I need for my chart... So... :/

Comment: I think we may need more information, and/or you example may need adjustment. Your example seems to enable "panning" in that clicking and dragging moves the lines around in the canvas, and that is indeed laggy, but it does not seem to enable any scaling. Is your goal to have a canvas element that stays put on the page, but responds to user input by moving/zooming the chart/lines within the canvas? Could you instead render the canvas, and then respond to user input by resizing and moving the whole canvas?

Comment: Hi @kenS thanks for the answer. It does enable scaling by the mouse wheel event (I tested on chrome only)

Comment: Ah, I'm on FF (61.0.2) right now, and the mouse wheel does not seem to scale for me

Comment: So are you able to move/resize the canvas rather than each line inside the canvas? I think performance would be better, so it might be a good idea if it fits your use case...

Comment: Actually I do not move or resize each line. I translate the whole canvas and scale it. The problem comes from simply drawing the lines: It takes to long to draw them. Im using `requestAnimationFrame` to animate and each frame everything is redrawn and takes too long... I cannot simply resize the "div" for the canvas because the lines would get distorted...